# C# skip hex charcters

Tags: c#, hex, skip

I'm using C# to read a file and I need to (sometimes) skip several bytes before outputting the next byte. For instance:

```
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

I wanted to skip the first two (or any given number) bytes then ouput the next one. Problem is, using the code below won't do it and I'm not sure how to. I need to be able to use the "skip" function throughout the program. If someone could help me I would be most grateful!

```
        String fileDirectory = "C:\\t.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDirectory);
        long stickNoteLength = fileDirectory.Length;

        int hexIn;
        String hex = "";

        for (int i = 0; (hexIn = reader.Read()) != -1; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
               hex = hexIn.ToString("X2");
            }
            MessageBox.Show(hex);
        }
```

Comment: the code you posted does not do what you are asking in the question

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
               hex = hexIn.ToString("X2");
            } is the same as without the for

Answer (score 2):

Your inner for loop on `x` is not consuming any characters from the file.  It's literally just taking the current byte and converting it to hex twice in a row, doing effectively nothing.  It's actually the outer loop on `i` that consumes characters.  You want to do something more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; (hexIn = reader.Read()) != -1; i++)
{
    if (i >= 2)
    {
        hex = hexIn.ToString("X2");
        MessageBox.Show(hex);
    }
}
```

Although it would be more efficient to just use the `Seek` function to jump directly where you want to read next:

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Current);  // jump two characters forward
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know where i want to begin it depends on a number of variables, also I dont know what "i" is going to be so wont be alble to use your solution, but thanks I do apperciat eyour help :)

Comment: OK, you've just dismissed my solution entirely and made no sense.  State clearly what you're trying to do!  I've answered your question completely as it stands right now... how can I read your mind??

Comment: Sorry. I need to read in a file using Hex, but at any given time I need to skip an amount of bytes then continue to read the file in, problem is I don't know how many bytes I will need to skip over and at no point will I know what the "I" will be so wont be able to use the to rotate through the number of bytes I need to skip.

Comment: @Jay: You need some criteria, such as a certain byte value that signals or something like that.  If you don't know how many bytes to skip then how is the computer supposed to know??

Comment: The computer will know as its based on file types, so it could be for exmaple 2, 4 10, 15, the number is not the problem, its getting it to read and skip that given number. So if I had 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39  and I wanted to skip say 3 bytes I would only want to output 34 35 36 37 38 39. But I wont know where abouts within the files the program is currently reading so can't base it on the int i.

Comment: @Jay: Skip what given number?  I have given you code above that can skip `n` bytes for any `n` from the current position.  I've also fixed your looping code so that you can advance byte-by-byte if you wish.  But how are you determining where to skip to?  What is your logic as you scan through the file manually, that you want to replicate in your program?  What do you mean by `based on file types`?  You're reading arbitrary files byte-by-byte manually, file types have nothing to do with it.